# Aix flag to reduce size of shared file

Tags: gcc, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking, xlc

I am using xlC (Version: 11.01.0000.0011).

While build i am using "-g" to have debug information in build.
there are many object files (>500) due to which resultant shared file (.so)  will have huge size.

I can't reduce optimization level.
Is there any way or flag is present by using which i can reduce size of shared file (.so) without much loss of debug info?

**EDIT**
File size if 2.3GB. due to which i can't link it to other places. I need to make it less than 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the linker option -bstabcmpct:2 at link time to compact the debug information in the shared file that is created.

Alternatively, you could specify the linker option -bstabsplit at link time, which will not put the debug information in the shared object that is created, but instead will create a separate file, with the extension ".stab", that contains the debug information. You can then tell dbx to use this .stab file with its -B option.

Comment: Thx a lot for info. I tried these options. My file size is 2.3GB. when i used "-bstabcmpct:2" it reduced to 2.1Gb but still till won't go less than 2 GB it's not supported by file system and can't link this file to other.
and on using "-bstabsplit" its giving "d: 0706-010 The binder was killed by a signal: Segmentation fault". 
Please help.

Comment: Is there any flag with which we can specify size of file to be linked. In other words can I somehow link a file with size 2.3GB?